# Save-File Action Required on CSV File for PowerCLI to Read Data

Tags: vba, excel, powershell, csv, powercli

I am using a VBA script to export data from an Excel spreadsheet to a CSV file in order to automate the VM creation process via the Import-CSV command with a PowerCLI script. The VBA script I am using is:

```
Function BuildValuesString(colIndex As String, rows As String) As String
    Dim val As Variant

    For Each val In Split(rows, ",")
        If Cells(val, colIndex) <> "" Then BuildValuesString = BuildValuesString & Cells(val, colIndex).Value & ","
    Next val
End Function
Function BuildNullStrings(numNullStrings As Long) As String
    Dim iNullStrings As Long

    For iNullStrings = 1 To numNullStrings
        BuildNullStrings = BuildNullStrings & "" & ","
    Next iNullStrings
End Function


Sub WriteCSVFile2()

    Dim My_filenumber As Integer
    Dim logSTR As String

    My_filenumber = FreeFile

    logSTR = logSTR & "1." & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "2." & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "3." & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "4." & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "5." & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "6." & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "Name" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "Cluster" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "VLAN" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "NumCPU" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "MemoryGB" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "C" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "D" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "App" & ","

    logSTR = logSTR & Chr(13)

    logSTR = logSTR & BuildValuesString("C", "18,19,20,21,22")
    logSTR = logSTR & BuildValuesString("C", "26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33")

    logSTR = logSTR & Chr(13)

    logSTR = logSTR & BuildValuesString("C", "18,19,20,21,22")
    logSTR = logSTR & BuildValuesString("C", "37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44")

    logSTR = logSTR & Chr(13)

    logSTR = logSTR & BuildValuesString("C", "18,19,20,21,22")
    logSTR = logSTR & BuildValuesString("C", "48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55")


Open "Z:\2016\Requests(Test)\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ".csv" For Append As #My_filenumber
    Print #My_filenumber, logSTR
Close #My_filenumber

End Sub
```

Once the data has been exported to the CSV file, I run the PowerCLI script to create the VMs using the names input under the 'Name' column that was extracted using the VBA script:

```
# Specify vCenter Server, vCenter Server username and vCenter Server user password
 write-host “Please specify vCenter Server and enter credentials” -foreground green
 $vc = read-Host "Connect to which vCenter Server?"
 write-host “Connecting to vCenter Server $vc” -foreground green

 $CSVPath = "$ScriptRoot\PROD_VMRequestTEST.xlsx.csv"    

 Connect-VIServer -Server $vc

 #$CSVFile = Import-Csv -Path $CSVPath

 Import-Csv -Path $CSVPath

 # Specify vCenter Server Virtual Machine & Templates folder
 $Folder = “Discovered virtual machine”
#
# Specify the vSphere Cluster

$Cluster = $_.Cluster

$esx = Get-Cluster $Cluster | Get-VMHost -State connected

Import-Csv -Path $CSVPath | %{

  Write-Host “Creation of VM $($_.Name) initiated”  -ForegroundColor green

  New-VM -Name $_.Name -VMHost ($esx | Get-Random) -Location $Folder

  Write-Host "Designating VLAN - '$($_.VLAN)'" -ForegroundColor green

  $VMhost = Get-vmhost $_.VMHost  
  $PortGroup = Get-VirtualPortgroup -name $_.VLAN -VMhost $VMhost  

  Write-Host "Power On of the VM $($_.Name)initiated" -ForegroundColor green

  Start-VM -VM $_.Name-confirm:$false -RunAsync

}
```

I am encountering errors if I attempt to run the PowerCLI script directly after having exported the data to the CSV file. The error says:

"Import-Csv: The member "1" is already present."

I can overcome this error if I manually open the CSV file and manually re-type the column name 'Name' within the CSV document and save file. It also seems to circumvent this error if I simply hit backspace and re-save the document as well, making no changes whatsoever. What could be causing this?

I would like to avoid doing this, is there anything that I can do to avoid having to manually re-save the document each time before running the PowerCLI script?

Comment: `I manually open the CSV file ... and save file` - Do you open it with Excel?  Or with a text editor?  Excel will make all sorts of changes to a CSV file as it saves it (saving numeric values using the displayed format, potentially placing quotation marks around strings, creating Y2K bugs in date fields, etc, etc), so the fact that you just retype something does not mean that the resultant file is not vastly different from the original file.

Comment: can you show us the first 2 lines of the CSV file from both before and after you open it in excel?  either as they display in notepad or as the results of a get-content?

Comment: @YowE3K It opens with Excel after it has been saved as a CSV. I just opened it with NotePad as well and the content appears to be correct - no quotation marks or anything out of place.

Comment: @MikeGaruccioPowerCLI Prior to re-saving the CSV File:       Desktop:\> Get-Content 'C:\Users\PROD_VMRequ
estTEST.xlsx.csv'
Srv. Descr.,E-mail,Env.,Prot. Level,Metro?,# VMs,Name,Cluster,VLAN,NumCPU,Memor
yGB,C_System,D_Homevg,App_eHealth,
CETS,email@emailaddress.com,Dev/QC,Protected,Metro Enabled,1,Test1.dev,vSphere 5.5 RND,363,1,8,30, 45, 150,

Comment: @MikeGaruccio After re-saving the CSV file (no content changes, just hit save again once it was open in Excel): PowerCLI Desktop:\> Get-Content 'C:\Users\PROD_VMRequ
estTEST.xlsx.csv'
Srv. Descr.,E-mail,Env.,Prot. Level,Metro?,# VMs,Name,Cluster,VLAN,NumCPU,Memor
yGB,C_System,D_Homevg,App_eHealth,CETS,email@emailaddress.com,Dev/QC,Protected,Metro Enabled,1,Test1.ro
ssdev,vSphere 5.5 RND,363,1,8,30,45,150

Comment: So it looks like there are some weird trailing commas and spaces but nothing that should prevent an import.  My best guess would be an encoding difference between what powershell is expecting and what your vbs is outputting.  you can use [This](http://poshcode.org/2059) to check encoding or just try all the possible values for the `-encoding` param on the import.  Also not sure if intentional for testing but you need to make sure the import where you assign the results to `$CSVFile`  is not commented (the other import is not doing anything)

Comment: I'm going to guess that the code you posted is not the code that generated that file.  (If it is, your error could be because you are adding dummy headings each time you append to the file, and the import is thinking that the dummy heading is data and that it exists multiple times.)  My guess of what is causing the error is what looks to be an extra comma at the end of your records - Excel seems to have stripped off the one from your second record but not the one from your first record.  Maybe change each `logSTR = logSTR & Chr(13)` to ` logSTR = Left(logSTR,Len(logSTR)-1) & Chr(13)`